# Double will not assign value from int array

Tags: java, file, int, double

In my program, I load some custom variables from a text file to use. This is the method that does this.

```
public int[] getGameSettings() {
String[] rawGame = new String[100];
String[] gameSettingsString = new String[6];
int[] gameSettings = new int[6];
int finalLine = 0;
int reading = 0;

try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("gameSettings.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
    int line = 0;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    // Store it
    rawGame[line] = strLine;
    line++;
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
    reading = line;
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < reading; a++) {
        if (!rawGame[a].substring(0,1).equals("/")) {
        gameSettingsString[finalLine] = rawGame[a];
        finalLine++;
        }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < finalLine; b++) {
    gameSettings[b] = Integer.parseInt(gameSettingsString[b]);
    }
return gameSettings;
}
```

I call that method from another class and save the array as gameSettings, then do the following:

```
contestedMovementPercent = (gameSettings[1]/100);
```

Contested movement always shows up at 0.0, even though if I print gameSettings[1] it comes out to exactly what it should be. contestedMovementPercent is a double. gameSettings is an array of int in both classes.

Is there some sort of casting I need to do? I thought int could be used like this.

Comment: This has been asked so many times. You are doing integer division. Change it to floating point division, by changing `100` to `100d`.

Comment: use `(gameSettings[1]/100.0);` .  Or `((double)gameSettings[1]/100);`

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dividing by an int, so it first computes it as an int and then converts it to a double. Changing it to `gameSettings[1]/100.0` will compute it as a double.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
contestedMovementPercent = gameSettings[1] / 100.0;
```

By using a float as divisor, the integer is automatically cast to a float before the division.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing two ints will be cast to an int before it is assigned to the double. And int can only be a whole number so, in this case, either 0 or 1.

As mentioned in other answers, making either side a double will make the result of the division a double (so gameSettings[1] / 100.0).